# regex to remove anchor tags if it is outside of myclass

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove anchor tags using regex from the given string if it is outside of my class.

Input:

```
<p>Hi Hello <a href="#">World</a></p>. This is <div class="myclass">testing <a href="#">content</a>. some more content</div>. One more <a href="#"> Link </a>.
```

Output:

```
<p>Hi Hello </p>. This is <div class="myclass"> testing <a href="#">content</a>. some more content</div>. One more .
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is no nested tags of same kind, try [`(*SKIP)(*F)` like this](https://regex101.com/r/lO3eF1/1)  but better here in general to use a parser like  @Jan's provided answer Imho. Regex will get slow and unreliable on larger input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could (and should, btw) use a `DOM` way (it will be hard if not impossible with regular expressions alone). The approach here is to look for hyperlinks where there's no ancestor `div.myclass` and remove these from the DOM:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOF
<p>Hi Hello <a href="#">World</a></p>.
This is <div class="myclass">testing <a href="#">content</a>. some more content</div>.
One more <a href="#"> Link </a>.
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query("//a[not(ancestor::div[@class='myclass'])]");

// Loop over them
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}

// just to test it out
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

See it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/BQKb8e).

---

Looking at the comments, you seem to still favour a regex way (why ?).
`PCRE` has a `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism which would work in this (simplified) example as well:

```
<div\ class="myclass">
[\s\S]*?
</div>
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
<a[^>]*>.*?</a>
```

See a demo for this [**one on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aE6lQ9/2).
**Hint:** It **won't work** for nested HTML strings (`<div><div>`) or attributes like `<p title="</div>">` which are both valid `HTML` expressions (obviously).

Comment: Hi @Jan... thank you for the effort.. I'm looking for regex not in a DOM way.

Comment: @Ramesh: It will lead in a dead-end :)

Comment: Hi @Jan... Really it's a great solution. Thanks a lot.